# Android mobile GPS problem

Tags: android, gps

I was working on plotting my traveling ways using GPS in Android mobile phones(Samsung Galaxy GT 15801 & Micromax A60). But sometimes it gives me the wrong lat&long. I was in INDIA but it shows me somewhere in middle of Arabian sea and after sometime it shows correct lat&long. Help me to getout of this problem.

Comment: which provider your are using in your application.....

Comment: gpsProvider = gpsManager.getBestProvider(gpsCriteria, true);

Comment: just give a try to Network provider....remove criteria

Comment: I have tried that too but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

use in the activity

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener mlocListener = new GetGPS(LoginPanel.this);
     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
             mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

just use this as separate class

```
    public class GetGPS implements LocationListener 
{
    GlobalVariable globalInstance;

    public GetGPS(Context context)
    {

    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {

        //location.getLatitude();
            //location.getLongitude();


    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
        //alertDialog.showMessage("Please Turn On your GPS", "GPS Turned Off");

    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

    } 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {

    }
```

Comment: I have used the same critreias, but also same problem.

Comment: i have same kind of code, but sometimes only i am getting the issue.